# T-SQL - Padding data points

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I have a series of data points in a table in an Azure SQL database. When plotted, the points have the following distribution:

[image]

What I am trying to do is add padding so that they have the appearance of being in a continuous line - or at lease more continuous than it is now.

I tried adding points between each point, but the problem with that is that it's all relative. If you look closely, you can see some of the points are blue, and some are dark red. The blue points are the ones I added, but the line looks the same.

I'm looking for advice on the logic I should use to solve this issue. I want to add x number of points between each data point based on the distance between the nearest points... if that makes sense.

Comment: What are you using to plot these? It might be preferable to use that tool to make it continuous rather than adding points in your query or table.

Comment: please provide example data

Answer (score 1):

I think this works

```
declare @t table (x smallmoney primary key, y smallmoney);
declare @inc smallmoney = 1;
insert into @t(x, y) values 
                     (1,  1)
                  ,  (5,  3) 
                  ,  (8,  4)
                  ,  (10, 5) 
                  ,  (11, 6);
with cte as 
( select x, x as x0, y, y as y0, cnt = cast(1 as smallmoney)
       , lead(x) over (order by x) as nextX
       , lead(y) over (order by x) as nextY
  from @t t 
  union all 
  select x + @inc, x0, y + @inc/(nextX-x0)*(nextY-y0), y0, cnt+1, nextX, nextY 
  from cte t 
  where x + @inc < nextX
)
select * 
from cte t 
order by t.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not confident that this is the best solution, but I think you could build off of it. Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e82a8/23/0)

```
SELECT x + COALESCE(((nextx-x)/10)*inc, 0) as x, y + COALESCE(((nexty-y)/10)*inc, 0) as y
FROM 
(SELECT x, y, nextx, nexty, inc.n + 0.0 as inc FROM 
 (SELECT x, y, lead(x) over (order by x) as nextx, lead(y) over (order by x) as nexty
 FROM points) p inner join (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) inc(n)
 ON nextx is not null or inc.n = 0
 ) a ORDER BY x
```

This will add 9 points between each point (10 points total, including the "real" one).

The basic idea is that I'm using `lead` for each row to get the next x and next y, then I join that to a hardcoded list of values 0 to 9. Then for each value, I increment x by 1/10 of the difference between nextx and x, and increment y by 1/10 of the difference between nexty and y.

The join condition `nextx is not null or inc.n = 0` is so that I only join inc(0) to the last x value (rather than joining 10 times).

You could change my hardcoded list of values and the hardcoded `10`s to increment differently. Similarly, you'd probably need some changes if you only want integers, but the principle will be the same.